# Checking a variable for a specific date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

[image]

I have a table with three columns: `start_date`, `client_id`, `active`.

I need to check the condition: if the user in the last month had `active = 1`, and at the time `start_date` `active = 0`, then assign the value 1, otherwise - 0

The dates in the table are slices for half a year, I only need to check the dates from `06.01.2021`

How can I do that?

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.  Do you have data on every day, for instance?

Comment: Added table view

Comment: _"Added table view"_  Adding a picture of your result set doesn't really help.   See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

One option might be this:

```
select *
from your_table a
where a.active = 0
  and a.date_column = :par_certain_date
  and a.id in (select b.id
               from your_table b
               where b.id = a.id
                 and b.active = 1
                 and b.date_column= add_months(:par_certain_date, -1)
             )
```

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(active) over (partition by id
                               order by date_column
                               range between '1' month preceding and '1' month preceding
                              ) as prev_active
      from t
     ) t
where active = 0 and prev_active = 1 and
      date = :certain_date;
```